# Content types of my images doesn't display

Tags: for-loop, twig, drupal-8

Why is it the images will not display if I'm going to loop them like this?

```
{% for item in content.field_room_gallery_pictures['#items'].getValue() %}
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 image-item">
    {{item.value}}
 </div>   
{% endfor %}
```

And when I fetched the data if there is or not using kint.. it will display an array with the value of 3 using this code..So it means in my `field_room_gallery_pictures` there is an array of data.

```
{{kint(content.field_room_gallery_pictures['#items'].getValue())}}
```

Answer (score 0):

have your tried this:

```
{% for i in 0..content.field_room_gallery_pictures|length %}
         {%if content.field_room_gallery_pictures[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value != "" and content.field_room_gallery_pictures[i]['#item'].entity.uri.value is not empty %}
            <div>
                {{ content.field_room_gallery_pictures[i]}}
            </div>
         {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

works fine for me.